# ClassLoader#getResource and dynamic CLASSPATH

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Does `ClassLoader#getResource()` method use different APIs to load resources depending in which context it was called? In particularly, I want to know: does it this method uses `ZipFile#open()` when it called within JAR context and does it uses `File` api when it called from IDE (without packaging to JAR)?

I ask because I have following problem: after launching JAR file it dynamically (at runtime) adds to it's own classpath new directory located on file system, and all work fine when I run it from IDE, but when I package my application to JAR it stops working - I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
```

So I think it is because `ClassLoader#getResource()` method within JAR context always uses `ZipFile` class to access files and dirs, but the target directory dynamically added to classpath shouldn't be accessed through `ZipFile` class (it should be accessed using simple `File` class).

Comment: How are you dynamically modifying the CLASSPATH exactly? Show your code.